# Jqueryui datepicker change class onselect doesn´t work

Tags: jquery-ui

I try to change the class of the selected Datepicker Field, but ist doesn´t work.

Here you find a fiddle with the code
https://jsfiddle.net/ztj6rd5m/

```html
<div id="Kalender"></div>
```

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Kalender").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(date, inst) {
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-datepicker-current-day")
        .removeClass("ui-datepicker-current-day")
        .children()
        .removeClass("ui-state-active");

      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar TBODY A").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == inst.selectedDay) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass("pickerActive");
          return;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
/* ]]> */
```

```css
.pickerActive {
  background: yellow;
}
```

I tried different cases, but the addClass doesn´t fire.
Can anyone helm me?
Thanx!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? You want the selected date to be in yellow color box?

Comment: Yes exact. The selected date should get the class "pickerActive" = yellow

Comment: The reason the class in not added is due to datepicker is recreated after each click. so you have to use some function other than `onSelect` to addclass. I am looking on that and will update you soon.

Comment: Could you check my answer and verify  ?

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Finally, as promised, i have found the solution. Check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/melvin007/m1wqvju8/3/).

As i have mentioned in the comment, the datepicker reconstructs itself at some point, that's why your code doesn't work. You can use a timeout function to apply your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Kalender").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(date, inst) {
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-datepicker-current-day")
        .removeClass("ui-datepicker-current-day")
        .children()
        .removeClass("ui-state-active");
      setTimeout(function() {
        inst.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass("pickerActive");
      }, 50);
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

I have modified your code a bit. I have removed the following condition check code

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar TBODY A").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == inst.selectedDay) {
```

to `inst.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day')` because you get the selected date instance from the `onSelect` function parameter.

In your css, you have to add `!important` to the background color as the background color from Datepicker Ui overrides your style.